# Hoffman and Kunze, Linear Algebra Sec 3.7 exercise 3

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

> Let $S$ be a set, $F$ a field, and $V(S;F)$ the space of all functions from $S$ into $F$:
>   $$ (f + g)(x) = f(x) +g(x)$$
>   $$(cf)(x) = cf(x)$$
>   Let $W$ be any $n$-dimensional subspace of $V(S,F)$ . Show that there exist points $x_1, x_2, ... x_n$ in $S$ and functions $f_1, f_2, ..., f_n$ in $W$ such that $f_i(x_j) = \delta_{ij}$.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121704/a-question-about-an-n-dimensional-subspace-of-mathbbfs) has been asked before and the proof of the problem involved induction. However I think this can be solved without using induction.

Attempt :

Define $T_x : V(S;F)\to F$ as $T_x(f)=f(x)$ where $x\in S.$ It is trivial to see that $T_x$ is a linear transformation. Now consider the restriction of $T_x$ on $W.$

Let $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ be a basis for $W.$ Using an elementary theorem we know there exists linear transformations $L_i : W\to F$ such that $L_i(f_j)=\delta_{ij}$ for each $i, 1\le i\le n.$

If I am able to show $L_i=T_{x_i}$ for some $x_i\in S$ then I am done.

> **I need help completing the proof this way OR please point a flaw showing why the proof cannot be going this way.**

Comment: why would you avoid induction? it is a nice mathematical tool

Comment: @supinf This problem is mentioned in the section "The Double dual," so there must be a way to do this involving it. I was just trying to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

It is not always possible to show $L_i=T_{x_i}$ for some $x_i$.

Consider $S=\mathbb R = F$.
Choose $W=\{f : f(1)=f(0), f(x)=0 \forall x\in \mathbb R\setminus\{0,1\} \}$ which is a $1$-dimensional subspace.
A basis of $W$ is given by $f_1(x)=\delta_{x,1} + \delta_{x,0}$.

$L_i$ can be defined as $\frac12 (T_1+T_0)$.
Thus it cannot be $T_{x_i}$ for some $i\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect because $L_1$ can instead be defined as $T_0$. When $W$ is finite-dimensional we can always find $x_i$ in $S$ such that $L_i = T_{x_i}$.

Answer (score 0):

*From the comments above.*

---

Since the proof is constructive, induction is a natural option.

However, if you wish you can avoid the language of induction by modifying the way you write the proof. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2518561/279515) in which this is done.

Moreover, the other answer by @supinf is incorrect, because $L_1$ can instead by defined as $T_0$. When $W$ is finite-dimensional we can always find $x_i$ in $S$ such that $L_i = T_{x_i}$.